# Jenkins 2.263.2 Cannot SSH to server from agent node

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-agent

I just upgraded Jenkins from 2.249.2 to 2.263.2. When I tried to build in agent node, I could not SSH to server by SSH Publishers.

```
Running as SYSTEM
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on native-slave in workspace /home/jenkins/jenkins_workspace/workspace/test1
SSH: Connecting from host [native-slave]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [dev] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [dev] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec timed out or was interrupted after 120,000 ms]
```

Another issue is that I could not download artifact from Jenkins agent workspace, the Jenkins webpage just loading
It just happen after I upgraded to new version.
Is there something wrong or what might causing the issue?